# NSViewに複数の画像を描画したい

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

Mac でアナログ時計のようなデスクトップアプリケーションを作成しようとしています。(Xcode 8 + Swift 3)
短針や長針などのPNG画像を重ね合わせて描画したいのですが、Swift自体初めてで正しい方法が分かりません。

まず NSView を拡張したクラスを作り、draw() メソッドをオーバーライドすることにし、ファイルパスから画像を読み込み、コンテキストを使って描き込もうと考えました。

#### 画像の読み込み

```
let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: path as String);
```

#### 描画処理

```
class MyView: NSView {

    override var isFlipped: Bool { return true }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        let bounds = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100);
        let context = NSGraphicsContext.current()?.cgContext;
        context.draw(image: self.image!, in: bounds)
    }
}
```

省略してありますが大きな流れは上記のとおりです。
読み込んだ image は NSImage ですが、 context.draw() の引数は CGImage でなければならないためエラーになっているように見えます。（Argument labels '{image:, in:}' do not match any available overloads）

```
image!.draw(in: bounds);
```

context を使わず上のようにすれば描画自体はできます。ただ回転処理などもする予定なので CoreGraphics を使っておいたほうが良いのではと思っています。（このあたりもよくわかっていません）

こういったケースでは通常どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

---

**追記**

NSViewの拡張クラスに isFlipped = true を追加

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 読み込んだ image は NSImage ですが、 context.draw() の引数は CGImage でなければならないためエラーになっているように見えます。

これは、`NSImage`のメソッド`cgImage(forProposedRect:context:hints:)`を使って、`CGImage`に変換します。

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current(),
              let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: path as String) else {
            return
        }

        var imageRect = NSRect(x: 32.0, y: 32.0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
        if let cgImage = image.cgImage(forProposedRect: &imageRect, context: context, hints: nil) {
            context.cgContext.draw(cgImage, in: imageRect)
        }
    }
}
```

---

> こういったケースでは通常どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

Core Graphicsフレームワークは、正直お勧めできません。アナログ時計といっても、イメージを動かすのは、静的イメージを描画するためのCore Graphicsは、なじまないと思います。QuartzCoreフレームワークか、ゲーム製作フレームワークのSpriteKitなどがお勧めになります。
ここでは、QuartzCoreフレームワークを使ったケースを紹介します。QuartzCoreでは、`CALayer`クラスが、描画の単位となっていて、`addSublayer()`によって、レイヤーを多層化し、複雑な構成を実現します。レイヤーごとに`CGAffineTransform`あるいは`CATransform3D`による座標変換を加えることができます。アナログ時計の時針、分針、秒針を、別々に動かすのに、適しています。

```
import Cocoa

class MyView: NSView {

    var subLayer = CALayer()
    // Storyboard、Interface Builderからインスタンスを生成した時の、初期化処理。
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        wantsLayer = true // レイヤー操作を有効にする。
        subLayer.contents = NSImage(named: "a.png") // レイヤーにイメージを貼り付け。
        subLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 50.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
        layer?.addSublayer(subLayer) // MyViewのviewのサブレイヤーにする。
    }
    // マウスをクリックしたら、
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        let affinTransform = subLayer.affineTransform()
        subLayer.setAffineTransform(affinTransform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 4.0))
        // レイヤーが45度ずつ回転する。

//        subLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(subLayer.transform, CGFloat.pi / 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        // CATransform3Dを利用する場合は、こちら。
    }
}
```

ここでは、QuartzCoreの、`CALayer`と`CATransform3D`を紹介しましたが、`CAAnimation`クラスと、そのサブクラスについても、勉強してみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。NSImage を CGImage に変換する方法で描画できることを確認しました（NSViewのflippedの関係で上下逆さまではありますが）。Core Graphicsそのものにこだわりはないので QuartzCore などのほうが良いようであれば検討してみます。